# PHP MySQLi prepared statement - should I include all the fields?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is an example:

```
if($stmt = $mysqli -> prepare("
    INSERT INTO 
    jos_virtuemart_product_categories 
    (
        virtuemart_product_id,
        virtuemart_category_id,
        ordering
    )
    VALUES
    (
        ?,
        ?,
        0
    )")) 
{

    /* Bind parameters
     s - string, b - blob, i - int, etc */
    $stmt -> bind_param("ii", $pid, $productcategory);

    /* Execute it */
    $stmt -> execute();

    /* Bind results */
    $stmt -> bind_result($result);

    /* Fetch the value */
    $stmt -> fetch();

    /* Close statement */
    $stmt -> close();
}
```

Now, if you look at one of my inserts, I am directly inserting 0, and not passing it through a prepare statement.

Is this workable?The reason I am asking is because I have statements with a TON of fields, where many fields are exactly the same for all rows, but only differs in perhaps two or three, which I get from a loop through a result set.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean _workable_? try it and see what happens

Comment: It is more of a "best practice" question than "will it work" question.

Comment: as it stands i see no problem with it

Answer (score 1):

If those are the same for all inserts, you can leave them hardcoded in the query - no need to make your code filled with useless things. The cleaner, the better - right?

Furthermore, you can alter the fields so that those values are the DEFAULT values - so that would eliminate the need to put them in the query.